# Ordering chords based on some property of the source data

Tags: d3.js

I have a chord diagram in d3 that looks something like this:

[image]

The color of each group is calculated base on a property of the source data (before being transformed to a matrix) and is looked up from the index of each group with something like this:

```
var groupPath = group.append("path")
    .attr("id", function(d, i) { return "group" + i; })
    .attr("d", arc)
    .style("fill", function(d, i) { return MySourceData[i].inArea ? "blue" : "red"; });
```

Now what I'd like to do is sort the chords so that all the blues are together and all the reds are together, but there doesn't seem to be a simple way to do that. I know you provide a function to `sortGroups` (and `sortSubGroups` for that matter), but it seems the arguments passed to the function are only the values of the chords and I would need to have the indexes to be able to figure out if they should be grouped together or not.

Is there any simple way to sort the groups based on some criteria that is ultimately derived from the index?

Comment: You could make the index part of the data.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff: Not sure how that would work. According to the [docs](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Chord-Layout#matrix) the matrix (used to generate the chord diagram) must be `a square matrix of numbers`. There doesn't appear to be a way to pass it an array of objects or something similar.

Comment: Hmm, you're right, this may not work.

Comment: Looks like the only way to do it is to keep track of the sum of the rows separately and then match in the comparison function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the best way to achieve this is to simply order my source data first before I transform it into a matrix. This works fine if the data isn't going to change (which, in my case it wasn't), but if you had data that might change and in changing might end up needing to be resorted, this would be a real pain since you'd need to reorder the matrix.